# Hasura SELECT permissions for table relationships

Tags: permissions, graphql, hasura

I'm building a forum. I have a really simple database setup:

```
Users: id, display_name, email, profile

Posts: id, title, content, user_id
```

The user_id is a foreign key to the Users table.

Permissions:

For inserting/updating, X-Hasura-User-Id must equal id and user_id for inserting into the Users and Posts table. (so they can only modify their own posts)

For selecting, I have it so a user can read any post, but they can only select the row of the User if id = X-Hasura-User-Id. This is so a User can only read their profile data.

However, for selecting, I obviously need the user to be able to access display_name of the user's table, to display the post's author.

Now I can obviously make it so for select, they only have access to this field, and everything works fine. I can return a GQL query that displays the posts and the author.

But doesn't this also mean that a user can just run a query to the Users table and get a list of all the display_names, essentially showing how many users I have?

Is there a way to set it up so that a user can only select their own info from the User's table, but like, if the query is 'coming from' the server, it can access the display_name? I know there are Admin roles etc but I don't think this applies here.

Answer (score 3):

> But doesn't this also mean that a user can just run a query to the Users table and get a list of all the display_names, essentially showing how many users I have?

Yes

> Is there a way to set it up so that a user can only select their own info from the User's table, but like, if the query is 'coming from' the server, it can access the display_name?

No

---

It's a valid concern to worry about data leakage in terms of how many users you have. But in general I would not worry about it.

However, there are a few things you could do to prevent this problem.

What you can do is:

- Limit the number of rows per request (https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/deployment/production-checklist.html#limit-number-of-rows-returned)
- Make sure `users` are not allowed to **aggregation queries**  (https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/queries/aggregation-queries.html#aggregate-fields)

Also what you can do is create a VIEW where the `display_name` is joined and added to the `posts` table.

Comment: Thanks for this. Glad to know I was thinking about it in the right way, and there wasn't some sort of security feature I wasn't aware of! I've implemented it in the way you suggest - thanks!

Comment: Happy to help. If you think my answer was enough you can mark my answer as accepted I think.